# jq: Turn json object values into arrays

Tags: arrays, json, grouping, jq, bucket

I have got the following array of objects (this is just an excerpt, also the objects are bigger):

```
[{
    "DATE": "10.10.2017 01:00",
    "ID": "X",
    "VALUE_ONE": 20,
    "VALUE_TWO": 5
  },
  {
    "DATE": "10.10.2017 02:00",
    "ID": "X",
    "VALUE_ONE": 30,
    "VALUE_TWO": 7
  },
  {
    "DATE": "10.10.2017 03:00",
    "ID": "X",
    "VALUE_ONE": 25,
    "VALUE_TWO": 2
  },

  {
    "DATE": "10.10.2017 01:00",
    "ID": "Y",
    "VALUE_ONE": 10,
    "VALUE_TWO": 9
  },
  {
    "DATE": "10.10.2017 02:00",
    "ID": "Y",
    "VALUE_ONE": 20,
    "VALUE_TWO": 5
  },
  {
    "DATE": "10.10.2017 03:00",
    "ID": "Y",
    "VALUE_ONE": 50,
    "VALUE_TWO": 5
  },

  {
    "DATE": "10.10.2017 01:00",
    "ID": "Z",
    "VALUE_ONE": 55,
    "VALUE_TWO": 3
  },
  {
    "DATE": "10.10.2017 02:00",
    "ID": "Z",
    "VALUE_ONE": 60,
    "VALUE_TWO": 7
  },
  {
    "DATE": "10.10.2017 03:00",
    "ID": "Z",
    "VALUE_ONE": 15,
    "VALUE_TWO": 7
  }
]
```

To simplify this for a web application, and also to reduce file size, I would like to convert the `"VALUE_ONE"`,`"VALUE_TWO"` and `"DATE"` values to arrays for each "ID" just like this:

```
[{
    "DATE": ["10.10.2017 01:00", "10.10.2017 02:00", "10.10.2017 03:00"],
    "ID": "X",
    "VALUE_ONE": [20, 30, 25],
    "VALUE_TWO": [5, 7, 2]
  },
  {
    "DATE": ["10.10.2017 01:00", "10.10.2017 02:00", "10.10.2017 03:00"],
    "ID": "Y",
    "VALUE_ONE": [10, 20, 50],
    "VALUE_TWO": [9, 5, 5]
  },
  {
    "DATE": ["10.10.2017 01:00", "10.10.2017 02:00", "10.10.2017 03:00"],
    "ID": "Z",
    "VALUE_ONE": [55, 60, 15],
    "VALUE_TWO": [3, 7, 7]
  }
]
```

Here it is important that you need to be able find the values that are linked to a certain time (date). As the input values for `"DATE"` are consecutive, you most probably do not need the `DATE` value anymore to find the requested `"VALUE.."` value. You can probably just use the index of the array for that (`index=0` is always `10.10.2017 01:00`, `index=1` is ... `02:00` etc.). 
Is it possible to do it like that? This would keep the file size even smaller.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution avoids `group_by` for two reasons:

- efficiency
- the `sort` used by `group_by` in jq version 1.5 might not be stable, which complicates things.

Instead we use `bucketize` defined as follows:

```
def bucketize(f): reduce .[] as $x ({}; .[$x|f] += [$x] );
```

To keep things simple, we will also define the following helper function:

```
# compactify an array with a single ID
def compact:
  . as $in
  | reduce (.[0]|keys_unsorted[]) as $key ({};
      . + {($key): $in|map(.[$key])})
    + {"ID": .[0].ID}
    ;
```

#### Solution

```
[bucketize(.ID)[] | compact]
```

This will ensure things are OK even if the set of dates differ across IDs, and even if the JSON objects are not grouped initially by date.

(If you want to drop "DATE" altogether in the final results, then replace the call to `compact` by `compact | del(.DATE)` in the line above.)

#### Output

```
[
  {
    "DATE": [
      "10.10.2017 01:00",
      "10.10.2017 02:00",
      "10.10.2017 03:00"
    ],
    "ID": "X",
    "VALUE_ONE": [
      20,
      30,
      25
    ],
    "VALUE_TWO": [
      5,
      7,
      2
    ]
  },
  {
    "DATE": [
      "10.10.2017 01:00",
      "10.10.2017 02:00",
      "10.10.2017 03:00"
    ],
    "ID": "Y",
    "VALUE_ONE": [
      10,
      20,
      50
    ],
    "VALUE_TWO": [
      9,
      5,
      5
    ]
  },
  {
    "DATE": [
      "10.10.2017 01:00",
      "10.10.2017 02:00",
      "10.10.2017 03:00"
    ],
    "ID": "Z",
    "VALUE_ONE": [
      55,
      60,
      15
    ],
    "VALUE_TWO": [
      3,
      7,
      7
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks. Works great and is easy to adapt.

Answer (score 1):

With *2-step* reduce(it doesn't look beautiful but works):

```
jq 'reduce group_by(.ID)[] as $a ([]; . + [ reduce $a[] as $o 
   ({"DATE":[],"VALUE_ONE":[],"VALUE_TWO":[]}; 
    .DATE |= .+ [$o.DATE] | .ID = $o.ID |.VALUE_ONE |= .+ [$o.VALUE_ONE] 
    | .VALUE_TWO |= .+ [$o.VALUE_TWO]) ] )' input.json
```

The output:

```
[
  {
    "DATE": [
      "10.10.2017 01:00",
      "10.10.2017 02:00",
      "10.10.2017 03:00"
    ],
    "VALUE_ONE": [
      20,
      30,
      25
    ],
    "VALUE_TWO": [
      5,
      7,
      2
    ],
    "ID": "X"
  },
  {
    "DATE": [
      "10.10.2017 01:00",
      "10.10.2017 02:00",
      "10.10.2017 03:00"
    ],
    "VALUE_ONE": [
      10,
      20,
      50
    ],
    "VALUE_TWO": [
      9,
      5,
      5
    ],
    "ID": "Y"
  },
  {
    "DATE": [
      "10.10.2017 01:00",
      "10.10.2017 02:00",
      "10.10.2017 03:00"
    ],
    "VALUE_ONE": [
      55,
      60,
      15
    ],
    "VALUE_TWO": [
      3,
      7,
      7
    ],
    "ID": "Z"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using [reduce](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Reduce), [setpath](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#setpath(PATHS;VALUE)), [getpath](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#getpath(PATHS)), [del](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#del(path_expression)) and [symbolic variable destructuring](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Variable/SymbolicBindingOperator:...as$identifier|...).  It will collect all the values for keys other than `ID` and `DATE` (eliminating the need to hardcode `VALUE_ONE`, etc.) in parallel arrays.

```
reduce (.[] | [.ID, .DATE, del(.ID,.DATE)]) as [$id,$date,$v] ({};
    (getpath([$id, "DATE"])|length) as $idx
  | setpath([$id, "ID"]; $id)
  | setpath([$id, "DATE", $idx]; $date)
  | reduce ($v|keys[]) as $k (.; setpath([$id, $k, $idx]; $v[$k]))
)
| map(.)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZFda4MwGIXv@yteJBcGoviBK6tXBXtRGOtN99FJGDJD63TqanQbtX99NlrKqtThJrnw@J48npO8vlfuTnKmy5k0kXRNFcvQ9DFo@kTTJCLNHfH9UbzcT2/uZs@LW@EztJNcPiykibUnFwlGP8FsE8Y9BPOXDFaLYPQQzlus2gS9neF6QIvVv87B7CdYwwjnLZ46hPY5mANadAhXf7@LDkG3OgRaVlvm5y8MZNWlUIKrzh0Cao0l4LNIrnUjMcXgZeCiwCfI9zgjqKAg7/b2CMQjrxlPPb6RGwMcg1FcRixe802zVQw@hbeErG0VSaldT/GlaQMizebaVf/56DsFR0UZsq/MPeZDoahidyAo/AEULgopxiM8KuHNS2UVV9V3kvIgibNKUeI8ipQgTnMuxNb7UJKcC3EA)

Answer (score 0):

If your data set is small enough, you could just group them up by id and map to the desired results. It won't be super efficient compared to a streaming solution, but will be the simplest to implement using builtins.

```
group_by(.ID) | map({
    DATE: map(.DATE),
    ID: .[0].ID,
    VALUE_ONE: map(.VALUE_ONE),
    VALUE_TWO: map(.VALUE_TWO)
})
```

Comment: `group_by` will only produce correct results if the underlying sort is stable, which is not always the case with jq 1.5 and earlier.